# Is it possible to build offline app with Appcelerator and Rhomobile?

Tags: appcelerator-mobile, rhomobile, offlineapps

I have recently found those two look-alike solutions/IDE for cross-mobile development: Appcelerator and Rhomobile (I know there are more) and I have questions regarding those two platform:

1) I believe the only way to build the view is using HTML, which I like alot the ideas. But, does that mean the application itself isn't available if the mobile is offline?

2) Do you guys know if it's possible to publish the application to the App Store and Google Store?

3) Are there any simulator for different mobile and do they support all those slide/tab events?

4) And finally, are there a way to transfert the App on your mobile phone without having to publish it anywhere.

Please note that I have no knowledge at all about mobile app dev and those two solutions (Appcelerator, Rhomobile) would be perfect for me as I am familiar with Javascript and HTML.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have only used appcelerator but:

1) a webview is like a browser without the address bar, it simply parses HTML, where it gets it from is up to you. If you write the HTML and pass in a file well then yes it can be offline, if it is used to parse a response from a webpage well then no as it needs to send a http request to the webpage.

As many people seem to mistake (for a reason unknown to me as all the documentation states other wise), appcelerator is not the same as phonegap, appcelerator uses its own javascript based API to allow developers to make native apps, it is NOT a webview wrapper. It is offline by default and allows you to send http requests if you need something online.

2) yes you can publish to the app store and the google store from appcelerator, the documentation walks you through the process.

3) Appcelerator requires you to download either the IOS sdk or Android SDK which come with simulators, appcelerator / the emulators support the standard events found on these devices.

4) With Android to can build a .apk file and distribute however you wish, with IOS the only way is to publish to the app store. the only other way is to make a mobile website instead of an application